# php discounts for different ages and members

Tags: php, percentage

I am attempting to create a program which can calculate the amount of discount for different ages and members. People aged under 12 can a 50% discount and a additional 10% if their a member. People aged under 18 or over 65 can have a 25% discount and an additional 10% on top if their a member. 
My program only seems to work if the age is below 12 does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix (go easy on me i'm new to programming).

```
$ticketPrice = 25;
$age = 25;
$membership = 'Yes';
$finalPrice;
$discount;
$memberDis;



if($age < 12) {

    $finalPrice = 25 / 2;

} else if($age < 18) {

$discount = 25 * 0.25;
$finalPrice = 25 - $discount;

} else if($age < 65) {

    $discount = 25 * 0.25;
    $finalPrice = 25 - $discount;
} else if($membership = 'Yes') {

    $discount = $finalPrice * .10;
    $memberDis = $dicount * 100;

}

echo "<br />";
echo "<h1>Ticket Example</h1>";
echo 'Inital Ticket Price: '."&pound".$ticketPrice;
echo "<br />";
echo "Age: ".$age;
echo "<br />";
echo "Member: ".$membership;
echo "<br />";
echo "Final Ticket Price: "."&pound".$finalPrice;
```

Comment: Everyone is less than 65. You have no ranges in your conditional tests. You have to test age *and* membership at each level.

Comment: `$membership = 'Yes'` You're assigning the value instead of comparing. Use `==` instead

Comment: You'd also want to remove the else from the membership check, since that would be done for all ages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should use the variable `$ticketPrice` instead of hardcoding its value in the `if ..else`.
- Inside your conditional statements, just determine the `$discount` first.
- Then outside the conditions, calculate the final price
- Comparison operator is `==` not `=`.
- Membership condition check should be moved out and separate from age checks.

Try

```
 // Initialize discount to 0
 $discount = 0;
 $finalPrice = $ticketPrice;

 if($age < 12) {

    // if age is less than 12 then 50% discount
    $discount = 50;

 } elseif($age < 18 || $age > 65) {

    // 25% discount for age < 18 or > 65
    $discount = 25;
 }

 if ($membership == 'Yes') {
    // additional 10% discount on membership
    $discount += 10;
 }


// now calculate the final price after removing discount
$finalPrice -= ($finalPrice*$discount/100);
```

Comment: You're limiting membership to a specific age range. Needs to be applicable to all.

Comment: Pst: you missed the case where `$age < 12` AND they are a member.  they get the 10% as well.  The membership check should be outside of age restrictions.

Comment: THESE are their words *" People aged under 12 can a 50% discount **and a additional 10% if their a member**. "*

Comment: @JayBlanchard oops :-/ corrected

Comment: it's not working its giving a final price of 0 when age is set to 15

Comment: @ProgramMe25 check the updated answer pls

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yes thankyou this has solved the issue. Cannot thankyou enough for your help.

Comment: It's not working for me, the calculation is wrong. For a 25 year old the price should be 16.25, not 22.50

Comment: @JayBlanchard there is no discounts for 25 year olds :P

Comment: the discount is for members and people under 12, 18 and over 65. A member that is over 25 would get 10% discount.

Comment: @ProgramMe25 since membership related discount calculation is separate from age now. My code should work for all members irrespective of age

Answer (score 0):

You can see a flowchart representation of your code, in order to make easy to understand what are you doing and why it doesn't work. [image]

As you can see the membership discount is applied if the age is greater or equals to 65, though you should see the difference between `=`, `==` and `===` operators.

according to your code structure, you should have:

```
<?php 

$ticketPrice = 25;
$age = 25;
$membership = 'Yes';
$finalPrice;
$discount;
$memberDis;



if($age < 12) {

    $finalPrice = 25 / 2;

} else if($age < 18) {

    $discount = 25 * 0.25;
    $finalPrice = 25 - $discount;

} else if($age < 65) {

    $discount = 25 * 0.25;
    $finalPrice = 25 - $discount;

} 

if($membership === 'Yes') {

    $discount = $finalPrice * .10;
    $finalPrice -= $discount;

}

echo "<br />";
echo "<h1>Ticket Example</h1>";
echo 'Inital Ticket Price: '."&pound".$ticketPrice;
echo "<br />";
echo "Age: ".$age;
echo "<br />";
echo "Member: ".$membership;
echo "<br />";
echo "Final Ticket Price: "."&pound".$finalPrice;
```